# REGEXP_LIKE not working as expected (novice expectations)

Tags: mysql

I want to remove women from men.

Each time I modify this line:

> WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name,'(men's)')

Inserting a ^ or $ to only match men's, it returns zero results. I have also tried adding ^ to the start.

```
SELECT name 
FROM table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name,'(men\'s)')
AND name LIKE '%shoe%'
LIMIT 5
```

```
name
Nike React Vision Men's Shoe - Grey
Nike React Vision Women's Shoe - Grey
Nike React Sertu Men's Shoe - Blue
Nike Revolution 5 FlyEase Men's Running Shoe - Blue
Nike Air Zoom Terra Kiger 6 Women's Trail Running Shoe - Pink
```

It is most likely my abhorrent MySql skills so any help would be most appreciated.

I have also tried an alternative syntax

```
WHERE name REGEXP '^(men\'s)'
```

Which also returns 0 results.

Comment: You could try mathcing the women instead. That seems a more roboust approach here. Would that work for you?

Comment: The `^` will matches the starting position of any line. The `$` is the opposite, meaning the end of the line. You should try to match `Men\'s` with a capital M to avoid to match women.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the RLIKE syntax and a word boundary to remove women from men:

```
SELECT name 
FROM products_en
WHERE name RLIKE '\\bmen\\b' 
AND name LIKE '%shoe%'
LIMIT 50
```

Thank you